# How can I create an empty commit using libgit2?

Tags: c, git, libgit2

I've been looking over the [libgit2 C API reference](https://libgit2.org/libgit2/), but I don't see how I could emulate the behaviour of `git commit --allow-empty`. Does libgit2 have a built-in way to create empty commits? If not, how does git create an empty commit under-the-hood, and how should I go about achieving the same behaviour using libgit2?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Call `git_commit_create` with the same tree as the parent commit. That is:

```
// Get parent somehow.
git_commit *parent = ...;

// Use the same tree as the parent.
git_tree *tree;
git_commit_tree(&tree, parent);

// Create the commit.
git_commit_create(..., tree, 1, parent);
```