# Using libgit2, how can an empty initial commit be created?

Tags: c, git, libgit2

Previously I had asked [how one could create an empty commit in libgit2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52188664/). That question was fully answered, however I wasn't clear enough when I initially asked it.

Using libgit2, how can one create an empty **initial** commit? The answer to [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52188664/) relies on having the parent commit object, which I don't know how to obtain for an empty repository. Perhaps something could be done using the empty tree object (whose hash can be generated with `git hash-object -t tree /dev/null`)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While writing my question, I came across an [example on the libgit2 reference](https://libgit2.org/libgit2/ex/HEAD/init.html), which had exactly what I needed.

> ```
> static void create_initial_commit(git_repository *repo)
> {
>    git_signature *sig;
>    git_index *index;
>    git_oid tree_id, commit_id;
>    git_tree *tree;
>
>    if (git_signature_default(&sig, repo) < 0)
>        fatal("Unable to create a commit signature.",
>              "Perhaps 'user.name' and 'user.email' are not set");
>
>    if (git_repository_index(&index, repo) < 0)
>        fatal("Could not open repository index", NULL);
>
>    if (git_index_write_tree(&tree_id, index) < 0)
>        fatal("Unable to write initial tree from index", NULL);
>
>    git_index_free(index);
>
>    if (git_tree_lookup(&tree, repo, &tree_id) < 0)
>        fatal("Could not look up initial tree", NULL);
>
>    if (git_commit_create_v(&commit_id, repo, "HEAD", sig, sig, 
>                            NULL, "Initial commit", tree, 0) < 0)
>        fatal("Could not create the initial commit", NULL);
>
>    git_tree_free(tree);
>    git_signature_free(sig);
> }
> ```

This function creates an empty initial commit. It reads the index from the empty repository, then uses that to obtains the ID of the empty tree (`4b825dc642cb6eb9a060e54bf8d69288fbee4904`), then uses that to obtain the empty tree, and finally creates the empty initial commit using that tree.